# find all possible combination of change in sml

Tags: sml

```
fun pp(amt)=
    let
      val c_50=ref 0;
      val c_10=ref 0;
      val c_x=ref 0
    in
      while !c_50 <= (amt div 500) do
        (while !c_10 <= (amt div 100) do
          (if ((500 * !c_50) + (100 * !c_10)) = amt
           then print("500won =>" ^ Int.toString(!c_50) ^
                     " 100won =>" ^ Int.toString(!c_10) ^ "\n")
           else
             c_x := !c_x +1 -1;
             c_10 := !c_10+1);
             c_50 := !c_50+1)
    end;
```

I want to print all possible combination of change in SML, but c_50 is not changed.

For example, if I run `pp(500)` I want the following output:

> 500won => 0 100won => 5
>   500won => 1 100won => 0

but now my program is only prints

> 500won => 0 100won => 500

and it's over. How do I fix this?

Comment: (1) Something seems to have gone wrong when you copied your code here. For example, `10           print("500won =>"^Int.toString(!c_50)^" 100won=>"^Int.toString(!c_    10)^"\n")` is not valid. (2) Please format your code for readability. A little whitespace goes a long way. (3) Why are you relying so heavily on `ref` and `while`? You should either write this in an ML-ish way, or use a language that's better-suited to the way you want to do it.

Answer (score 2):

### Some general advice

1. Avoid imperative structures like `while` and `ref` when recursion is an option.
2. Make your function readable. It is unclear by the name of the function and the variable names what it's supposed to do. A couple of comments don't hurt, either.
3. Divide the problem into sub-parts that are more easily solvable. (This is usually easier when you've figured out how to solve it, so rewriting your solution after a crude first attempt is perfectly fine.)

### Some concrete advice

Let's formulate the problem as `val allPossiblePayments : int -> int list -> int list list` so `allPossiblePayments sum coins` lists all possible payment options of coins taken from `coins` that sum to `sum`. We might assume that `sum >= 0` and that all coins are positive, or we might make the function robust and check for this.

```
fun allPossiblePayments sum coins =
    if sum < 0 then raise Fail "Negative amount" else
    if List.exists (coin => coin <= 0) cs then raise Fail "Non-positive coin value"
    else allPossible sum coins (* non-robust version *)
```

And before we get started, we might want to prepare a few tests.

- There is exactly one way to pay out zero no matter the coins available: The empty bag of coins;

  ```
  val allPossiblePayments_1 = allPossiblePayments 0 [1, 2, 5] = [[]]
  ```
- The special case when all coins divide the total amount:

  ```
  val allPossiblePayments_2 = allPossiblePayments 5 [1, 2, 5]
      (* should contain [5], [2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1] and [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] *)
  ```
- A case when the [greedy choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) is not an option:

  ```
  val allPossiblePayments_3 = allPossiblePayments 11 [2, 5]
      (* should contain [[5, 2, 2, 2]] *)
  ```

The reason I haven't expressed `allPossiblePayments_2` and `allPossiblePayments_3` as proper tests (returning a bool, or throwing an exception) is that it's a little difficult: We haven't fully specified if a "payment option" includes *different ordering* of the same coins (**permutations**; e.g. `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]` are treated differently and both should be included in the result) or not (**combinations**; e.g. `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]` are treated the same and only one of them should be included in the result). Combinations is probably the right choice here. So testing these functions becomes a little problem in itself (comparing permutations/combinations).

### Solving it for permutations

Even though the same combination of coins will occur several times this way, it's a little simpler.

```
(* putInFront x [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]] = [[x,a,b,c],[x,d,e,f],[x,g,h,i]] *)
fun putInFront coin (subResult::subResults) = (coin::subResult) :: putInFront coin subResults
  | putInFront x [] = []

fun allPossible 0 coins = [[]]
  | allPossible sum coins =
    let val validCoins = List.filter (fn coin => coin <= sum) coins
        val subResults = List.map (fn coin => (coin, allPossible (sum-coin) validCoins)) validCoins
        val totResults = List.map (fn (coin, subResult) => putInFront coin subResult) subResults
    in List.concat totResults end
```

The code explained:

1. For any amount `sum`, we only look at the `validCoins` that are smaller than `sum`.
2. For each of these valid coins, `coin`, we form a pair `(coin, subResult)` that is computed by solving this problem recursively, but for a smaller amount `sum-coin`. (Also, if a coin is too big for `sum`, it will also be for `sum-coin`.)
3. For each pair `(coin, subResult)`, the solution to the sub-problem of size `sum-coin`, `subResult`, can be a solution to the problem of size `sum` if we take each sub-result and add `coin` in front of it.
4. Since each `subResult` has type `int list list` and we have a *list of those*, we flatten the list once. (This means that for each recursive call as *sum* grows smaller, we explode the problem into many lists of results (one for each coin) and merge those into one list of results.

Testing this function,

```
- allPossible 5 [1,2,5];
val it = [[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,2],[1,1,2,1],[1,2,1,1]
         ,[1,2,2],[2,1,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[5]] : int list list
```

we see that all of these are valid, but that some are permutations of others.

### Solving it for combinations

Getting only combinations can be a little tricky. A bad way would be to generate all permutations, sort them and then remove duplicates. It's bad because we generate unnecessary amounts of results only to spend even more energy getting rid of them again.

A better way would be to generate them in sorted order and exclude duplicates as they are generated. One can do this by adding a coin to the head of a result *only* if it's greater than or equal to the biggest coin in that result.

```
fun putInFront _ [] = []
  | putInFront validCoin ((coin::subResult)::subResults) =
    if validCoin >= coin
    then (validCoin::coin::subResult) :: putInFront validCoin subResults
    else putInFront validCoin subResults
  | putInFront validCoin ([]::subResults) = [validCoin] :: putInFront validCoin subResults
```

Testing with this version of `putInFront` instead of the old one,

```
- allPossible 5 [5,2,1];
val it = [[5],[2,2,1],[2,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]] : int list list
```

It isn't completely obvious that we must throw away all of `(validCoin::coin::subResult)`. Another option could have been to only throw away `validCoin` and keep `coin::subResult` when `validCoin < coin`. If we do that, we get some funky partial results,

```
- allPossible 5 [5,2,1];
val it = [[5],[2,2,1],[2,2],[2,1,1,1],[2,2],[2,1,1],[2,1],[2],[1,1,1,1,1]] : int list list
```

Conversely, one may argue that if `validCoin < coin`, where `validCoin` is some coin and `coin` is the largest coin in the partial result `coin::subResult`, then the solutions where `validCoin` is included have already been counted and `validCoin` can be thrown away this time.

### Cleaning up

Here is a cleaned up version of the code above, along with some explanations and thoughts;

```
fun putInFront c =
    List.mapPartial
      (fn cs => case cs of
          [] => SOME [c]
        | (cmax::_) => if c >= cmax then SOME (c::cs) else NONE)

fun concatMap f xs = List.concat (List.map f xs)

fun allPossible 0 _ = [[]]
  | allPossible sum coins =
    let val validCoins = List.filter (fn coin => coin <= sum) coins
    in concatMap (fn coin => putInFront coin (allPossible (sum-coin) validCoins)) validCoins end

fun allPossiblePayments n cs =
    if n < 0 then raise Fail "Cannot handle negative amounts" else
    if List.exists (fn c => c <= 0) cs then raise Fail "Cannot handle non-positive coin values"
    else allPossible n cs
```

1. Since `putInFront` really filters and then maps, these are combined into `List.mapPartial` which, when its auxiliary function returns `NONE` filters that element away, and when `SOME y` includes `y` as part of the result.
2. Instead of writing `fun putInFront c subResults = List.mapPartial (fn ...) subResults`, one can simplify this using an [Eta-conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) into `fun putInFront c = List.mapPartial (fn ...)`.
3. A minor thing; in `putInFront`, when returning `SOME (c::cs)`, that `cs` actually contains `cmax` as the head element, so we don't need to include it again like we did in the previous version. This saves constantly reconstructing the list for non-optimizing SML compilers.
4. Since generating multiple results using `List.map` and then concatenating those lists of results into a single list using `List.concat` is such a common thing to do, you'll find `concatMap` to be a convenient contraction of the two.
5. Creating the `(coin, subResult)` pairs was actually redundant, since we pass both of these directly onto `putInFront` after. But it usually helps to think of solving problems in smaller steps at a time.
6. You could move `putInFront` and `allPossible` so they are only visible to `allPossiblePayments`, e.g. using `local ... in ... end`, but you could also pretend that you plan to put these functions inside a module with [*strong ascription*](http://jozefg.bitbucket.org/posts/2015-01-08-modules.html).

Comment: Another tour de force answer.

Comment: Hehe :) I should probably become proficient with an ML dialect that people actually use.